# Caret obtain train & cv predictions from model to plot

Tags: r, r-caret

I've trained a simple model:

```
mySim <- train(Event ~ .,
               method = 'rf',
               data = train,
               tuneGrid = tg)
```

Optimising the two `nnet` parameters `weight_decay` and `size` of the hidden layer. I'm new to trying out `caret` so what I would usually do is plot the `train error` and `cv error` for each model build. To do this, I'd need to have the predictive values of my `train` and `validation` pass.

This is the first time I've used cross validation so I'm a little unsure how I can go about getting the predictions from the train and hold-out set at each `tuneGrid` iteration.

If I have a grid search of length 3 (3 models to build) and 5-fold cross validation I assume I'm going to have 15 sets of train & holdout predictions for each model.

The plot I'm essentially looking to build is:

[image]

Where my y-axis is a performance metric, lets say entropy loss for the sake of classification with `nnet` and the `size` grid search values on the x-axis increases from 0 - max.

Is there a way in which I can extract the predicted values from the train / holdout set during `trainControl` cross validation?

I've looked through some of the attributes `train` returns but not sure if I'm missing something.

I know I lack code in this question but hopefully I've explained myself.

**Update** 
I am correct in assuming setting the following parameters in `trainControl` will return the predictions allowing me to create this plot:

- `returnResamp`
- `savePredictions`

Comment: carets `train` keeps only the hold out predictions. If you specify `savePredictions ="all"` it will save hold out predictions for all hyper parameter combinations. However it does not save the train set predictions. You could generate them afterwards with the knowledge which indexes were used for the hold outs. This info is the `model$pred` slot of the object returned by `train`. If you wish I could show you. But to pick the best hyper-parameters you just need the red curve. mlr library has an option to keep both hold out and train predictions and metrics.

Comment: model$pred returns `NULL` when I check. Can you also link me to that MLR package. Thanks

Comment: added examples with `mlr` and `caret`. mlr tutorials are [here](https://mlr-org.github.io/mlr-tutorial/release/html/task/index.html)

Comment: In the model object returned, do I have access to each of the models? I've found the indexes in `model$pred` but unsure how I'd make predictions on the model with a hidden layer of size 10 compared to one with size 5.

Comment: @Sam the returned object does not save all the models only the last one on all the data. But you can save all the model predictions on the hold out data to calculate any metric you wash after the fact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`carets::train` keeps only the hold out predictions. If you specify `savePredictions ="all"` it will save hold out predictions for all hyper parameter combinations. However it does not save the train set predictions. You could generate them afterwards with the knowledge which indexes were used for the hold outs. This info is the `model$pred` slot of the object returned by train. `mlr` package has an option to keep both hold out and train predictions and metric.

Here is an example on how to perform the requested operation with **mlr** library:

```
library(mlr)
library(mlbench) #for the data set
```

I will use the Sonar data set:

```
data(Sonar)
```

create a task:

```
task <- makeClassifTask(data = Sonar, target = "Class")
```

create a learner:

```
lrn <- makeLearner("classif.nnet", predict.type = "prob")
```

get all tune-able parameters for a learner:

```
getParamSet("classif.nnet")
```

set which ones you would like to tune and the range:

```
ps <- makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("size", lower = 3, upper = 5),
  makeNumericParam("decay", lower = 0.1, upper = 0.2))
```

define resampling:

```
cross_val <- makeResampleDesc("RepCV",  
                              reps = 2, folds = 5, stratify  = TRUE, predict = "both")
```

how the search will be performed (grid in this case):

```
ctrl <- mlr::makeTuneControlGrid(resolution = 4L)
```

get everything together:

```
res.mbo <- tuneParams(lrn, task, cross_val, par.set = ps, control = ctrl, 
                      show.info = FALSE, measures = list(auc, setAggregation(auc, test.sd),  setAggregation(auc, train.mean), setAggregation(auc, train.sd)))
```

you can define many measures in a list (the first one is used to select hyper parameters all the other are just for show).

extract the results:

```
res <- mlr::generateHyperParsEffectData(res.mbo)$data
```

plot:

```
library(tidyverse)

res %>%
  gather(key, value, c(3,5)) %>%
  mutate(key = as.factor(key)) %>%
ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x = size, y = value, color = key))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x = size, y = value, color = key))+
  facet_wrap(~decay)
```

a bunch of warnings about geom_smooth since there are only 3 points per fit

[image]

and an example on how to do it in **caret** just on the hold out samples:

```
library(caret)
```

create a tune control

```
ctrl <- trainControl(
  method = "repeatedcv",
  number = 5,
  repeats = 2, 
  classProbs = TRUE,
  savePredictions = "all",
  returnResamp = "all",
  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary
)
```

create a grid of hyper parameters:

```
grid <- expand.grid(size = c(4, 5, 6), decay = seq(from = 0.1, to =  0.2, length.out = 4))
```

tune:

```
fit <- caret::train(Sonar[,1:60], Sonar$Class, 
                 method = 'nnet',
                 tuneGrid = grid, 
                 metric = 'ROC', 
                 trControl = ctrl)
```

plot:

```
fit$results %>%
  ggplot()+
  geom_point(aes(x = size, y = ROC))+
  geom_smooth(aes(x = size, y = ROC))+
  facet_wrap(~decay)
```

[image]

Comment: I thought trained set predictions being saved to `mySim$finalModel$fitted`?

Comment: @GregV This is true for some models like `lm` and `glm` and is a feature of specific methods (models) and not carets feature.