# How to create a custom model (using loop/sub-models trick in caret)

Tags: r, machine-learning, r-caret, gbm

I'm fighting with this issue for an embarrassingly long time. I feel like an absolute cretin, as the answer is probably painfully obvious, but I can not find a single thread that explains how to do this.

Documentation part about custom model creation feels for me like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg7FT.jpg). I feel like somewhere during my education I missed some very specific class, that everybody remembers now, but me, because all I find is "yea, just create a custom model, and done".

### Actual questions here:

I want to get predictions for every single iteration of `gbm` in `caret`. In `gbm` I can just use `n.trees` in `predict(..., n.trees = 1:100)` for example, and it's done.

In `caret` apparently for I need to use something called sub-models trick, which means - if I understand correctly - that I have to create my own custom model.

But I can see in `getModelInfo('gbm')`, that there is some kind of loop function!

```
$gbm$loop
function (grid) 
{
    loop <- plyr::ddply(grid, c("shrinkage", "interaction.depth", 
        "n.minobsinnode"), function(x) c(n.trees = max(x$n.trees)))
    submodels <- vector(mode = "list", length = nrow(loop))
    for (i in seq(along = loop$n.trees)) {
        index <- which(grid$interaction.depth == loop$interaction.depth[i] & 
            grid$shrinkage == loop$shrinkage[i] & grid$n.minobsinnode == 
            loop$n.minobsinnode[i])
        trees <- grid[index, "n.trees"]
        submodels[[i]] <- data.frame(n.trees = trees[trees != 
            loop$n.trees[i]])
    }
    list(loop = loop, submodels = submodels)
```

How do I use that? Why is it not working by default? Do I actually need to create a custom model - or maybe not?

Disclaimer 1: I do not want to use any crossvalidation. I just want to pull out predictions, for every iteration of a single  gbm run.

Disclaimer 2: I don't want to use `predict.gbm()` on `$finalModel`, as I want to also test some other algorithms, which also make use of that sub-model trick. I do not want to use all the different algorithm specific `predict()` functions, because then why should I even bother with caret.

I do not even know what should I put as a replicable example. There is no problem with the code. I just have no idea how this thing is supposed to work.

Comment: So you would like predictions on the training data for each tree? What would be the point of this? I might be able to help if you would like to pull cross validated/bootstrap predictions for each tree without creating a custom model. From my knowledge caret does not make it easy to pull train predictions for any model since they mean very little.

Comment: @missuse Pretty much that, but I wish to get predictions for each tree for both training and test data, to later create learning curves for presentation purposes. I want to have full control over the parameters, and I want to reduce all black box type elements as much as possible, so as of now I’m not interested in cross validation options. I also do not understand why caret makes that so hard to achieve. That functionality seems to me rather important for comparing different algorithms performance per time on presentations.

Comment: algorithm performance can not be estimated on the train data, this is most likely the reason why caret's author chose not to provide easy access to train data predictions.

Comment: @missuse I specified I wish to also (and mainly) pull predictions for test data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how to pull the desired predictions for the test data for each tree:

```
library(caret)
library(mlbench) #for the data set
data(Sonar) #some data set I always use on stack overflow

res <- train(Class~.,
             data = Sonar,
             method = "gbm",
             trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", #some evaluations scheme
                                      number = 5,
                                      savePredictions = "all"), #tell caret you would like to save all,
             tuneGrid = expand.grid(shrinkage = 0.01,
                                    interaction.depth = 2, 
                                    n.minobsinnode = 10,
                                    n.trees = 1:100)) #some random values and all the trees

res$pred #results are stored in here
```

Basically the code you are showing in the post tells caret not to tune all n.tree models but rather just tune the one with `max(n.trees)` per each hyper parameter combination and then to use it to obtain predictions for `n.trees < max(n.trees)`

some plot

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(res$results)+
  geom_line(aes(x = n.trees, y = Accuracy))
```

[image]

You can also opt not to `savePredictions = "all"` since that makes for a memory hungry train object. But rather to use `res$results` in which you would calculate all the desired metrics.

Comment: This looks a lot like what I wish to obtain. But is it possible to do the same with no crossvalidation? (trainControl(method = “none”)). Sorry I’m on mobile, editing is rather limited here. Because when I did that, than caret was telling me that I can not specify a range of values for a parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately no since with `method = “none”` no predictions are provided and you can specify just one hyper parameter combination.

Comment: That is really weird that this is not allowed. It seems like my only option is to create a custom model I guess? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: You can extract both train and test prediction with `mlr` library. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754886/caret-obtain-train-cv-predictions-from-model-to-plot